# how to send custom return messages from functions?

Tags: java

I am having a function that does a DB operation and sends a `boolean` value for success/failure. suppose it fails, i want to send the failure reason as a return value.

for now, i have defined return value as a string. if it is failure i return `"failure: reason"` and if it is success, i return `"success"`. but this is not good practice.

Comment: why do you think it is not good practice?

Comment: That's what the Exceptions are for. In case of failure, throw an Exception, and put the reason in the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you use `throw exception` for. You can very well change your method signature and set the return value to be boolean. Then create a custom Exception class:

```
public class MyCustomException extends RuntimeException {
    // define error code, error message etc.
    // create getters & setters
}
```

After that, whenever you find a reason for failure, do this:

```
if (some_failure_reason == true) {
    throw new MyCustomException(error_code) ;
}
```

In your controller (or service), catch the exception:

```
try {
    // call the method in question
} catch (MyCustomException mce) {
    if(mce.getErrorCode() == some_error_code) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On Failure you can throw a checked `custom Exception`.

```
public class DBException extends Exception{
  public DBException(String exp){super(exp)}
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the error messages static final Strings so other classes will be able to access them, example:

```
public static final String DB_FAILURE_REASON1 = "failure: reason1";
```

Otherwise create a subclass of Exception, and either store specific reasons as the Exception's `msg` or create further subclasses of your subclass for specific failure reasons:

```
public class MyDBFailure extends Exception
```

And add a `throws` to your method:

```
public String myDBMethood() throws MyDBFailure
```

Comment: but that doesn't look like a proper standard way :(

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should throw Exceptions (you can customize them if you none of the existing ones suit your needs). Your approach is more C like.

If you really can't use Exceptions (which will provide who ever is using your code to decide what to do), you might resort to an Enumeration, listing some possible outcomes, if not all. Note though that such an approach can be quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own `Result` class with a string field containing return value and getter (or overload `toString()` method):

```
 public class Result {
     String message;

     public Result(String message) {
          this.message = message;

     }

     public String toString() {
          return message;
     }
 }
```

Another option is to use enums.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an exception on failure and call the function in a try-catch statement.

You can create a global variable of type string and set that on failure and return false, and then you can get the error message out of the global variable.

You can return an array in which the first element is the return value and the second is the error message.

My personal favorite is the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CustomException` with return error codes codes. A better way of identifying error reasons is to define it inside enums so that whenever error condition occurs you can construct exception with Enums.

Also you can extend this paradigm to handle multiple error codes in single exception if required.

whenever error condition is detected create instance of `CustomException` and then throw it.

```
  //Error Condition detected
  if(input<10)
  throw new CustomException("Invalid Input it should be greater 
    than 10 ", ErrorCode.ErrorCode1);
```

You can use Multiple error conditions like below.

```
  if(intput>100 && input < 1000)//Just a sample case.
   throw new CustomException("Invalid Input it should be not be greater
     than 100 and less than 1000 ", EnumSet.of(ErrorCode.ErrorCode1,
     ErrorCode.ErrorCode2));
```

Source for `CustomException`:

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {

    private EnumSet<ErrorCode> errorCodes;// You can also maitain multiple
                                            // error codes for same
                                            // exception

    public CustomException(String message, ErrorCode errorcode) {
        super(message);
        this.errorCodes = EnumSet.of(errorcode);
    }

    public CustomException(String message, EnumSet<ErrorCode> errorcode) {
        super(message);
        this.errorCodes = EnumSet.copyOf(errorcode);
    }

}
public enum ErrorCode {
    ErrorCode1(1, "First Error"), ErrorCode2(2, "Second Error");
    int code;
    String reason;

    private ErrorCode(int code, String reason) {
        this.code = code;
        this.reason = reason;
    }
}
```